# pokemon go pokestops and gyms

Tags: pokemon-go

so I saw some posts about this already and they have been getting closed about pokestops and gyms not showing. In my case the server is not queuing and all pokestops and gyms have been removed from my town. This is not just a me issue I work in a hotel every guest I checked in tonight has this same issue as do my friends. It's almost like they shut my town off. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the game officially released in your country? Did your administrator maybe block it? (Have you tried it on mobile data or hotel wifi?)

Comment: Which town is it?

Answer (score 0):

Niantic have recently been removing certain Pokestops at the request of property owners, local authorities and "concerned individuals".

This is mostly used to remove stops that are on private property, are disrespectful (such as cemeteries), or unsafe to access. However, some local authorities have tried to get entire towns removed from Pokemon Go. Perhaps the Roald Dahl villain you elected succeeded.

It might also be that Pokemon Go was never released in your region. Niantic have been shutting down regions where the game isn't released. If this is the case wait until the game is actually released.